# When Google plugin for Eclipse 4.5 ( Mars ) would be available?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse, eclipse-mars

It's several weeks that Eclipse 4.5 (Mars) has released, but there is no news about official google plugin for this version yet.
Does anybody know when we can desire to have this plugin?

Comment: i'm using latest GPE in mars and it works fine. give it a try.

Comment: At least an official word from google that the old plugin is compatible with Eclipse Mars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official release for Eclipse Mars is here:

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.5

Answer (score 2):

The GPE is now being managed by the community.  The new URL for downloading the beta releases is: http://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/release.

Beta documentation can be found here:

https://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/

This beta release supports Mars.

Answer (score 1):

Updates for Eclipse Mars started going out Friday, March 25, 2016. You can install it manually from [devsite](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download) if necessary.